# Jekyll: _includes & layout questions

Tags: ruby, templates, github, jekyll, github-pages

I'm new to Jekyll and web programming in general. I've been looking around for some answer to the particular questions I have and have found none. If they are out there, they must have names I don't know.

A couple of questions about my new Jekyll site:

I am trying to use the `_includes` as basically a way of creating the "areas" of the site. I'd like to have an include for the header, footer, navigation, maybe even a sidebar, eventually, so that when I make a change to my site design, I only have to change the files there.

The problem I am having is that, while my `{% include name.html %}` Liquid is working for index pages (`siteurl.com/index.html` and etc.) which use `_layouts/default.html`, I also want to be able to use the includes in my posts which use `_layouts/post.html`.

Unfortunately, no matter what I try I cannot get the posts to render with my header, nav bar, and footer! The posts are generated with only the post content. I thought the point of using Jekyll was to separate post content from post layout and use Jekyll to stitch them together at the end?

All of the code for my project is online at [github.com/illiooo/illioo.github.io](http://github.com/illioo/illioo.github.io) and the live site can be viewed at [illioo.github.io](http://illioo.github.io).

I'm using standard Jekyll directory structure, so my layouts are in `_layouts` and my includes are in `_includes`. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your posts you have to write

```
layout: post
```

instead of

```
layout: post.html
```

Just omit the .html file extension.

Comment: Thanks!

However, it is only coincidence that my post and default layouts are the same; in fact, I intend to have different views of posts than of other pages. What I'm mostly concerned about is that the posts are not rendered using the layout I specified.

Comment: Thanks! Actually, the problem I mentioned seems to have been because I was using layout "post.html" rather than just "post" in the YAML front matter. When you said "sufficient" I though you meant optional. Apparently it isn't!

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear. Of course it is not optional, you have to omit .html, otherwise it won't work. I will update my answer.